# How can I Sum Column Data according to date and then subtract this data from a column of another table on basis if same date of both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I Sum Column Data according to date and then subtract this data from a column of another table on the basis of the same date of both tables?

I am using **mySql** language

I have two tables and I want to subtract particle columns on basis of their dates. like My First Column Name is **Sales** having Columns **Date** **Total**.

The Second Table Name is **Expenses** and it has Columns **Date** and **Amount**

I want to Sum all the rows of both tables according to date(as one date can be repeated) using group by on both tables and then from the result of **Group By** used in both these tables, I want to subtract them on basis of same date on both tables and I want to show the result with Date after subtraction.

Comment: Can you give us a (small) example of what the tables contain, and what you want your sql output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sub-queries and join with group by as follows:

```
Select s.date, s.total - e.amount as result
from
(Select date, sum(total) as total
   From sales group by date) s
Join
(Select date, sum(amount) as amount
  From expenses group by date) as e
On e.date = s.date
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solved my problem